# Degree of prime power of an element

Tags: galois-theory, fields

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. For a field $F$, assume that $\deg(\alpha, F)=p$.
Is it necessarily true that $\deg(\alpha^q, F)=p$? Is there any counterexample?

It is not an exercise problem although it looks very simple. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: What makes you say it's not an exercise problem (or do you mean that you didn't happen to find it in a textbook)? You have $F\subseteq F(\alpha^q)\subseteq F(\alpha)$ with the degree of $F(\alpha)/F$ being the prime $p$. So what you're asking is whether it is possible for $\alpha^q$ to be in $F$. Suppose it is. Let $f(X)\in F[X]$ be the irreducible poly of $\alpha$ over $F$. Note that $g(X)=X^q-\alpha^q\in F[X]$ has $\alpha$ as a root, so $f(X)\mid g(X)$. Hence $f(X)$ is a product of terms of the form $X-\zeta\alpha$ with the $\zeta$ being primitive $q$'th roots of unity. Does that help?

Comment: Well, I simply thought that It is not an easy problem. I guess that you are giving a counterexample. As you mentioned, $ f(X)$ is a product of $p$ terms of the form $X-xi \alpha$.  Hence one needs to show that some product of $p$ terms of the form $X-xi \alpha$ is irreducible over $F$. How can you show it?

Comment: Please do not post to [math.se] and this site at the same time, especially not without mentioning it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476194/if-the-degree-of-alpha-is-prime-then-it-equals-the-degree-of-alphaq-for

Comment: @Joe Silverman: the problem is that the primitive qth roots of unity are not in the ground field. This question is more delicate than it seems and I don't know why it's on hold. A collegue of mine asked a question closely related to this in a Galois Theory final exam and several students handed in solutions like yours ;-) but in fact $\alpha^q$ can be in $F$! (as I found out when I was marking the question...). Just let $\alpha$ be a primitive $q$th root of unity and let $F$ be an appropriate field with $p$ a divisor of $q-1$.

Comment: @eric, I wonder whether the only counterexamples are those coming from $q$th roots of unity.

Comment: No! If you adjoin one cube root of 2 to the rationals to get $F$, and then let alpha be another one, then $F(\alpha)/F$ has degree 2 and is generated by something whose cube is in the ground field. The question is as subtle as the OP suggests and should not be on hold. As I say, I once found all this out whilst marking an exam where both the students and examiner had underestimated this question. I would answer if it was unonholded. Kummer theory does not apply when the $q$ th roots of unity are not in the ground field. Do I remember seeing @kconrad going on about this here a few years ago?